# A simple inequality in number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $0 < a,b,c <1$, then is the following inequality true?$$a^2(b+c)+b^2(c+a)+c^2(a+b)+ab+bc+ca-a-b-c \ge0$$

Comment: IfI haven't miscalculated, for all values equal 0.1 you get -0.264

Comment: Perhaps you are missing a condtion that $a + b + c = 1$?

Comment: @JanStout No. $a=b=c=1/3$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: The inequality is true if $a=b=c\in[0.5;1)$ and false if $a=b=c\in(0;0.5)$.

Comment: This isn't number theory. The tag and the title are wrong. It's about inequalities or algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly not when $a,b,c$ are close to $0$.

Comment: The inequality is true if $a=b=c\in[0.5;1)$ and false if $a=b=c\in(0;0.5)$.